# Joomla 3 Component page error

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I am trying to create a joomla component but I allways getting page 404. I have create a folder com_mycom in my component folder. Inside my_com I have created a php file to see if it works. Inside my php file I have the follwing code:

```
<?php

defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( '' );
echo '<div class="componentheading">Welcome to my Own Joomla Front end    Component</div>';

?>
```

but when I set in my url site/index.php?option=com_mycom I get a 404 page and does not the message. Does any one why I am doing wrong

Comment: What do you mean "to see if it works"?  What is the name of the file? WHere is it located in the component file structure? Have you read any documentation about how to create a component?

Comment: I'm trying to create a component in my joomla site. I am reading about this on how to create a joomla component and created this one the is the message "Welcome to my Own Joomla Front end" appears when I wright the follwing url:site/index.php?option=com_mycom but only getting 404 page and the message does not show. What I am I missing

Comment: Do you have a template in your view folder for the default view? What is the default view? Where is this file located and is it a template file or a class?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my issue. I used an online tool to create joomla component. The tool is [Component Creator](https://www.component-creator.com/pt_br/) a very good tool. It created all my folders for me. The administrator folder, Component Folder and media folder where I have my css and js. The was not showing because I was not installed in my extension table. With this tool I created my zip file and after installing in my BackOffice the component now the page works fine.